# Color list to gtk Image

Tags: python, image, gtk, pygtk, pixel

How can i make a `gtk.Image` that is made from an list of `gtk.gdk.Color`.

```
color_list = [gtk.gdk.Color(100*i,100*i,100*i) for i in range(10)]
image = gtk.Image()
draw_image_from_list(color_list, image)
```

I need that procedure and the image would be just one column of pixels:

```
|color1|
|color2|
|color3|
     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a widget that almost does what you want: https://github.com/ptomato/LaserCam/blob/master/src/ColorMapIndicator.py

It's a `gtk.DrawingArea` instead of a `gtk.Image`, but I decided against using an image since they are more meant for displaying image *files*, not for drawing on. It displays the colors in a horizontal bar 128 pixels wide and 10 high, but that should be easy enough to change. And finally, it does it from an array of numbers, not of `gtk.gdk.Color`, but it looks like you generate those from numbers anyway in your example.